# Backbone.Undo.js not working as desired. In fact not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, model, undo-redo

I am trying to implement [Backbone.js Undo manager](https://github.com/osartun/Backbone.Undo.js#backboneundojs-methods) with my existing code. My application is kind of template builder.

Here is console.log of main object.
http://screencast.com/t/0JDfCY7l

As you can see it has palette and editor object. I want to register undo, redo with that.
Here is my code for undo manager intergation.

```
var UndoManager = new Backbone.UndoManager;
    UndoManager.register(app.editor,app.palette,DdBuilder); // Pass any number of arguments
    UndoManager.startTracking(); // Start observation after instantiation
    $(".fusion_undo").click(function () {

        alert(UndoManager.isAvailable("undo")); //returns false always
        UndoManager.undo();
    });
    $(".fusion_redo").click(function () {
        UndoManager.redo();
    });
```

I believe it is simple integration and I am missing some minor details. Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `app.editor`, `app.palette` and `DbBuilder` trigger Backbone-events? The UndoManager adds listeners to the objects that are passed to the `register`-function. If you haven't [extended the supported UndoTypes](https://github.com/osartun/Backbone.Undo.js#supporting-other-events-and-modifying-built-in-behavior) your UndoManager [supports](https://github.com/osartun/Backbone.Undo.js#supported-events) the `add`, `remove`, `reset` and `change` events and creates undoable actions from these events.

You may want to test whether your objects trigger these events by logging them into the console.

```
app.editor.on("all", console.log, console);
app.palette.on("all", console.log, console);
DbBuilder.on("all", console.log, console);
```

If they trigger one of the events and `isAvailable("undo")` still returns false afterwards then there must be a tougher problem, but try this at first.